# Redirecting to success page after message send

Tags: php, forms, email, redirect, post

I am trying to send email from the contact form so sending email is working but  after sending I want to re-direct to the contact_formsuccess.php ,but it's not re-directing to that page its remains on the same, can any one how to make it thanks

```
<?php
$target_path = "/var/www/xxxxxx/cv/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

//print $target_path; 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}


$name=$_POST['senderName'];
$email=$_POST['senderEmail'];
$mobile=$_POST['senderMobile'];
$company=$_POST['senderCompany'];
$inquiry=$_POST['inquiry'];
$message=$_POST['message'];

include 'class.phpmailer.php';
include 'class.smtp.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
//$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail

$mail->Host = "mail.authsmtp.com";
$mail->Port = "25"; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "xxxxx";
$mail->Password = "xxxxx";
$mail->SetFrom("xxx@xxxxxxx.com");

$mail->Subject = $inquiry;
$mail->Body = "Name:$name"."<br/><br />"."E-mail:$email"."<br/><br/>"."Mobile:$mobile"."<br/><br/>"."Company:$company"."<br/><br/>".$message;
$mail->AddAttachment($target_path);
$mail->AddAddress('xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com');


 if(!$mail->Send())
 {
     echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
 }
 else
 {
     echo "Message has been sent";

     header('Location: contact_formsuccess.php');
 }  



?>
```

Comment: Turn your error reporting on you should be getting Warning: "Headers already sent"

Comment: why its still in the same page

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try to put `header('Location: contact_formsuccess.php');` after the 
`$mail->AddAddress('xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com');` maybe it will works

Answer (score 3):

When you modify the HTTP headers via the `header` php function, you must do it before any other output. To simplify, a HTTP request is composed of an header and then a body. When you call `header`, it will modify the HTTP header part. When you do any output (here your `echo "Message has been sent";`, it will "close" the header section and fill the body section. This is why you can not change HTTP headers after any output.

You should try to delete your `echo` line (as well as any output that can be printed before the call to `header`) and just keep the `header` part.

Comment: thanks for your answer can you modify my code i tried removing echo but is not rediredcting

Comment: There are one potential echo after the `move_uploaded_file` and one just before your `header` function.

Comment: i tried like this i removed all the echo just put header("Location: contact_formsuccess.php"); it reditect but mail not sending

Comment: Then it's not a problem with redirection but mail sending instead. Please open another question with your new problem description.

Answer (score 0):

If you are redirecting to other page than remove the `echo` `message` because it's createing issue for you or try code something like this to send user to other page.

```
if (headers_sent()) {
   echo("<script>location.href = 'user.php';</script>");
} else {
   exit(header("Location: user.php"));
}
```

Comment: This suppose that javascript is activated. It is not always the case (e.g., the script is not called from a browser).

Comment: Yes, I know but as per the current issue/script of @xavi it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You could always do it in JavaScript

```
 if(!$mail->Send())
 {
     echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
 }
 else
 {
     echo "Sending message(s)...";

    echo "<SCRIPT type='text/javascript'>
            window.location='contact_formsuccess.php?updated=true&updatedmsg=" . urlencode('Message has been sent.') . "';
        </script>";

 }
```